# Printing to-be-displayed values in oct2py

Tags: python, matlab, octave, oct2py

In **Matlab**/**Octave**, if an expression does not end with a semicolon *;* to silence it, its value is displayed on the output. However, this does not happen in **oct2py** - these values are printed only in case an exception happens later. I'd like to either capture and display the output, or just let it pass to the standard output - these are debug prints.

I suspect the answer will have something to do with the logger parameter of *Oct2Py()* constructor, but I just can't figure out how to put it together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding logging, I was mainly confused about the interplay between *basicConfig()*, *setLevel()* and so on.

If you want **oct2py** to behave like **Octave** regarding output printout (I still don't really understand why it doesn't), replace the constructor call

```
oc = oct2py.Oct2Py()
```

in your code with

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
oc = oct2py.Oct2Py(logger=logging.getLogger())
```

and you should finally see all the output, just prefixed with "DEBUG:root:". (If one would really care, it should be possible to get rid of that.)